# Google maps API - GStreetviewPanorama - Remove Address Overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

 panoramaOptions = { addressControl: false,navigationControl: false };
  panorama = new GStreetviewPanorama(smallNode,panoramaOptions);
 GEvent.addListener(panorama, 'error', function(errorCode) {
         if (errorCode == 600) {
           smallNode.innerHTML = 'No Streetview data was found.';
         }
       }); 
  panorama.setLocationAndPOV(marker.getLatLng());
marker.openInfoWindowTabs(tabs);

 });
```

Hi - I am displaying a Street View from a lat long value, but the address displayed in the Panorama (street View) is slightly off from the address I have stored in the database. For example, the overlay will display "91 xxx Street" in the top right corner of the Street View map, when I have "93 xxx Street" as my marker which was geocoded.

I would like to remove the address overlay and user photos overlay from this map, using the above code as a reference - could you please assist in removing the address and photo overlays?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the user photos, but not the address.

The properties available for `GStreetViewPanoramaOptions` are available in [the reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GStreetviewPanoramaOptions).

In particular, to remove user photos:

```
var panoramaOptions = { features: { userPhotos: false } };
```

`addressControls` and `navigationControls` are not supported options.

Comment: By the way, you should consider migrating to v3. It has support for [hiding the address control](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewPanoramaOptions).